# How do I synchronize access to an array list accessed by multiple threads?

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I have an ArrayList that needs to be read from and written to from multiple components of my GUI.  I have drastically reduced the amount of code to try to illustrate the problem in this concise code segment below.

The parent frame might have a number of internal frames, and each internal frame will need its own instance of this ArrayList.  However, all of the subcomponents of a specific internal frame will need access to the same instance of this ArrayList, so that additions and deletions are maintained in one true ArrayList for the specific internal frame.  For this example, all the data in the ArrayList needs to be in memory.  However, I will later add code to update a persistent data file every time a change is made in memory.

Here is my reduced code segment.  Can anyone show me how to change this code so that it gives me the read/write access that I seek?  Also, any links to relevant articles would be appreciated.

ParentFrame.java:

```
package testGlobalArrayList;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import java.util.*;

public class ParentFrame extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JLayeredPane desktop;
JInternalFrame internalFrame;

public ParentFrame() {
    super("parent frame");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
    Panel p = new Panel();
    this.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    this.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
    this.setSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    final int DELTA = 40;
    int offset = DELTA;
        int ifWidth = 400;
        int ifHeight = 200;
        internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("internal frame", true, true, true, true);
        internalFrame.setLocation(offset, offset);
        offset += DELTA;

        JTabbedPane jtp = createTabbedPane();
        internalFrame.add(jtp);

        // want to make this ArrayList read/write accessible to every GUI component below this level            
        ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myArrayList.add(8);
        myArrayList.add(6);
        myArrayList.add(7);

        desktop.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setSize(new Dimension(ifWidth,ifHeight));
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
private JTabbedPane createTabbedPane() {
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    jtp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,300));
    createTab(jtp, "Tab1");
    createTab(jtp, "Tab2");
    return jtp;
    }
private void createTab(JTabbedPane jtp, String s) {
    if(s=="Tab1"){
        TestGUI myTimeSeriesGUI = new TestGUI();
        jtp.add(s,myTimeSeriesGUI);
    }
    else{jtp.add(s, new JLabel("TabbedPane " + s, JLabel.CENTER));}
    }
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ParentFrame myParentFrame = new ParentFrame();
    myParentFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

TestGUI.java:

```
package testGlobalArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.Box;

public class TestGUI extends JPanel{

TestGUI(){
    Box verticalBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    verticalBox.add(new TestPanel());
    verticalBox.add(new TestPanel());
    verticalBox.add(new TestPanel());
    this.add(verticalBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
void anotherMethod(){
    // want to be able to add or delete records to same ArrayList here
    myArrayList.add(5);
    myArrayList.add(3);
    myArrayList.add(0);
    myArrayList.add(9);
}
}
```

TestPanel.java:

```
package testGlobalArrayList;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {
public TestPanel (){
    this.setBackground(getRandomColor());
    this.setBorder( new EtchedBorder() );
    this.setSize(150,20);
}
void anotherMethod(){
    //want to be able to add or delete records from same ArrayList here
    myArrayList.remove(1);
    myArrayList.remove(2);
    myArrayList.remove(3);
}
    private static Color getRandomColor(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    float r = rand.nextFloat();
    float g = rand.nextFloat();
    float b = rand.nextFloat();
    Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
        return randomColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't *if(s=="Tab1")*, use *.equals()*.

Comment: @HannoBinder +1 it only works correctly here because the string literals are interned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the arraylist along in the constructors (and make it a field)

```
public class ParentFrame extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLayeredPane desktop;
    JInternalFrame internalFrame;
    private List<Integer> myArrayList;

    public ParentFrame() {
        super("parent frame");
        myArrayList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myArrayList.add(8);
        myArrayList.add(6);
        myArrayList.add(7);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        Panel p = new Panel();
        this.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        this.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        final int DELTA = 40;
        int offset = DELTA;
        int ifWidth = 400;
        int ifHeight = 200;
        internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("internal frame", true, true, true, true);
        internalFrame.setLocation(offset, offset);
        offset += DELTA;

        JTabbedPane jtp = createTabbedPane();
        internalFrame.add(jtp);




        desktop.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setSize(new Dimension(ifWidth,ifHeight));
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    }


    private void createTab(JTabbedPane jtp, String s) {
        if(s=="Tab1"){
            TestGUI myTimeSeriesGUI = new TestGUI(myArrayList);
            jtp.add(s,myTimeSeriesGUI);
        }
        else{jtp.add(s, new JLabel("TabbedPane " + s, JLabel.CENTER));}
    }
}
```

TestGui becomes

```
public class TestGUI extends JPanel{
private List<Integer> myArrayList;

TestGUI(List<Integer> myArrayList){
    Box verticalBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    verticalBox.add(new TestPanel(myArrayList));
    verticalBox.add(new TestPanel(myArrayList));
    verticalBox.add(new TestPanel(myArrayList));
    this.add(verticalBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.myArrayList = myArrayList;
}
void anotherMethod(){
    // want to be able to add or delete records to same ArrayList here
    myArrayList.add(5);
    myArrayList.add(3);
    myArrayList.add(0);
    myArrayList.add(9);
}
```

and TestPanel

```
public class TestPanel extends JPanel {
private ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList;
public TestPanel (ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList){
    this.setBackground(getRandomColor());
    this.setBorder( new EtchedBorder() );
    this.setSize(150,20);
    this.myArrayList = myArrayList;
}
void anotherMethod(){
    //want to be able to add or delete records from same ArrayList here
    myArrayList.remove(1);
    myArrayList.remove(2);
    myArrayList.remove(3);
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving me an example.  I think I was already doing that in my actual application, but your code helped me understand.  I am going to work with my code a bit before replying more to this post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference to the global list (or to an object encapsulating this global list) to each of the components. Passing it in their constructor is the easiest way to go:

ParentFrame.java:

```
    List<Integer> myArrayList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myArrayList.add(8);
    myArrayList.add(6);
    myArrayList.add(7);

    JTabbedPane jtp = createTabbedPane(myArrayList);
    internalFrame.add(jtp);

...

private JTabbedPane createTabbedPane(List<Integer> list) {
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    jtp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,300));
    createTab(jtp, "Tab1", list);
    createTab(jtp, "Tab2", list);
    return jtp;
}
private void createTab(JTabbedPane jtp, String s, List<Integer> list) {
    if ("Tab1".equals(s)){
        TestGUI myTimeSeriesGUI = new TestGUI(list);
        ...
```

TestGUI.java:

```
private List<Integer> list;
TestGUI(List<Integer> list) {
    this.list = list;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you.  But can you give me an example with my code.  Or perhaps a link to an article.  I am having a hard time knowing exactly what you mean.

Comment: +1.  Thank you.  I am going to examine my actual code for a while before responding to this post further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a controller to maintain these kinds of resources. For java UIs you can use a controller that you access through a singleton method anytime you need it. This should act as the traffic cop to your app.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you mind showing me how to modify my code to accomplish that?  I posted this because I have been working on it for a while and I need something more specific.  A link to an article would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Well look up MVC and singleton if you want 1,000 articles apiece. MVC is a great idea, but it's always a bitch to implement because, when you think about it, a user interface is the perfect example of violation of encapsulation, because its whole goal is to display the internals of your model for the world to see.

So what I would do in your position is have main instantiate the controller using your factory method, then have the control build your screens for you. Any state information that transcends the screen itself should only go to the controller and the controller will dispatch the data

Comment: For the singleton, let's say you have a class called MainController. Inside you'd have a variable

static MainController myController;

Now you write a factory method such:

static public synchronized MainController getInstance(){
    if(myController==null){
        myController = new MainController();
    }

    return myController;
}

Then you make your constructor private so only you can construct it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Service locator pattern (which might also help you with the requirement of persisting to disk).

Something like

```
public ServiceLocator() {
  private static ArrayHandler handler=new ArrayHandler();

  public static IArrayHandler getArrayHandler() {
    return handler;
  }

}
```

Then you can create your ArrayHandler to handle creating and keeping track of your arrays.  So in your code you could get your array with something like:

```
ServiceLocator.getArrayHandler().getArray("myarray");
```

This way you don't need to pass parameters around and change method or constructor signatures when you need "no more variable".  Anyway, this is a pattern I like and feel comfortable with. YMMV.  Cheers.